# How to make sure space is preceded and followed by a letter in a regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for a string that will be a person's name. These are the following restrictions:

- Can contain at most 1 - symbol (can be none)
- Can contain at most 1 ' symbol (can be none)
- There cannot be two spaces next to each other
- A space must be proceeded and followed by a letter (a-z or A-Z)
- There is a max of 20 characters for the string
- The string must start with a letter (a-z or A-Z)

This is the expression I have so far:

```
^(?!.*[ ]{2})(?!(.*?-){2})(?!(.*?'){2})([a-zA-Z])([(?<=[a-zA-Z]) (?=[a-zA-Z])][a-zA-Z0-9\-']*){0,19}$
```

What I am missing is checking to make sure the space is followed and preceded by a letter. Any advice on how to incorporate that is very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: add a valid positive test case and use https://regex101.com/

Comment: Perhaps like this `^[a-zA-Z](?!.*(['-]).*\1)(?!.*  )(?=.{0,19}$)[a-zA-Z0-9'-]*(?:[a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'-]*)*$` https://regex101.com/r/UPySgp/1

Comment: Or with a lookbehind also allowing `a b` like  `^[a-zA-Z](?!.*(['-]).*\1)(?!.*  )(?=.{0,19}$)[a-zA-Z0-9'-]*(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z]) [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'-]*)*$` https://regex101.com/r/QKXOw0/1

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you for that! It works :) I took out the numbers since those weren't allowed (forgot to mention that rule also) and it is perfect. You made what I wrote better too, so thank you!

Comment: While this can be done with a regular expression, it is maybe clearer and simpler to write some code for the check.

Answer (score 1):

For these specific requirements, you might use:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?!.*(['-]).*\1)(?!.*  )(?=.{0,19}$)[a-zA-Z0-9'-]*(?: (?<=[a-zA-Z] )[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9'-]*)*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` Match a char a-zA-Z
- `(?!.*(['-]).*\1)` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 times `'` or `-` using a capture group with a backreference `\1` to match the same what is captured in group 1
- `(?!.*  )` Negative lookahead, assert not 2 spaces
- `(?=.{0,19}$)` Positive lookahead to assert 0-19 chars as the first char is already matched
- `[a-zA-Z0-9'-]*` Optionally match any of the listed without a space
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?<=[a-zA-Z] )[a-zA-Z]` Match a space and assert a char a-zA-Z before it
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9'-]*` Optionally match any of the listed chars
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tOEOdl/1)

Or without the numbers

```
^[a-zA-Z](?!.*(['-]).*\1)(?!.*  )(?=.{0,19}$)[a-zA-Z'-]*(?: (?<=[a-zA-Z] )[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z'-]*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KN0uz6/1)